# Make a unity game look like it has crashed C#

Tags: c#, winapi, unity-game-engine, windows-10, metaprogramming

I want to make my Unity game look like it has crashed (Unresponsive Application Crash, Not a code exception crash).

There probably is some function in the Windows API you can call to emulate this.

I have also seen a game called "Pony Island" do this before, so it certainly is possible. However I don't own a copy nor can I decompile a steam game.

If there is a way to actually hang the program while still being able to bring it back at anytime that solution is preferable, this seems to be unlikely.

To be clear, I want it to look legitimate, so I would prefer the windows API be used to change the window color and generate a pop-up, instead of having them in unity as GUI objects or something similar. I also don't really care about cross-compatibility because the Mac API appears to be hard to implement and even harder to test (on a Windows machine), and most likely won't be compatible with as many hacky features as the Windows API is.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do this safely would be to run some script setting `time.timeScale = 0` - effectively 'freezing' the game, while simultaneously playing the windows 'error' sound effect.

*(Note: You may have to also pause audio sources and particle emitters from this script, I've not used timescale before an am unsure if it affects these)*

---

I know you suggested against using UGUI but an image with no source placed over the entire screen, with it's colour and alpha tweaked could very easily emulate the 'frozen screen' too.

You could also look into ways to forcibly 'restore'/change fullscreen mode of the window (if it is played in full screen)

Comment: The problem with a UGUI is the corners of the window, and X Square and _ buttons are not changed unlike in a real crash, to users running a windows theme that changes these it would be far to obviously a troll, however the time.timeScale = 0 bit is very useful, and i will most likely use it in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to achieve that by using Thread.Sleep(int)
so while in the main thread, i would call that to freeze the entire unity loop for an amount of seconds eg 5 seconds = 5000ms

and check whether you want to continue the crash or not. for example, but not tested, (i don't have unity at my office environment)

Be carefull with this, as this will freeze it for real, you can't do any operation while it still freezing.

```
public class Crasher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isCrash = false;
    //The crash in seconds
    public float crashDuration = 5;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (isCrash)
        {
            //Freeze the applicaion for amount of milliSeconds
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(crashDuration * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The unity sided crash effect is exactly what i need, but sadly this method does not produce the [program].exe has stopped working effect that a hanging program on windows does, this information is useful though, and i will probably use this over time.timeScale = 0.

Comment: This code as it is - is a bad idea, and will cause the crash indefinitely if it is ever set to 2, as the thread will sleep for 5000 milliseconds *every frame*. You might want to consider using a co routine for this behaviour, and setting  `isCrash` back to false whenever the `crashDuration` is up.

@LittleK00PA setting timescale will be safer, and allow you to still run some code if needed during this time, Thread sleeping will not.

Comment: @LittleK00PA forgot to tag you in previous comment sorry (not sure if an edit + tag notifies you?) - You'll want to take note of what I've said in my previous comment before considering this method.